# Setting options for create_join_table migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some issues. I'm new to RoR

I'm trying to create a join table using Rails migration. Documentation of this is here...
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_join_table

When I do...

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserOffer users offers
```

...it creates the following migration

```
class CreateJoinTableUserOffer < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_join_table:users, :offers  do |t|
         t.index [:user_id, :offer_id]
         t.index [:offer_id, :user_id]
      end       
    end
   end
```

and when I do...

```
rake db:migrate
```

it creates...

```
-- Table: offers_users

-- DROP TABLE offers_users;

CREATE TABLE offers_users
(
 user_id integer NOT NULL,
 offer_id integer NOT NULL
)
WITH (



OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE offers_users
 OWNER TO sudeepkaushik;

-- Index: index_offers_users_on_offer_id_and_user_id

-- DROP INDEX index_offers_users_on_offer_id_and_user_id;

CREATE INDEX index_offers_users_on_offer_id_and_user_id
 ON offers_users
 USING btree
 (offer_id, user_id);

-- Index: index_offers_users_on_user_id_and_offer_id

-- DROP INDEX index_offers_users_on_user_id_and_offer_id;

CREATE INDEX index_offers_users_on_user_id_and_offer_id
 ON offers_users
 USING btree
 (user_id, offer_id);
```

> What I want to do is that I first of all want the table name to be users_offers instead of offers_users, for this you can specify the :table_name in the create_join_table migration. I'm not able to get the syntax of setting this option correctly. Need help here!
>
> 2nd, I noticed that this migration doesn't create the foreign keys that I would expect with the Users and Offers tables. Need your comments here also. Do I need to manually create the foreign keys myself?

Comment: try this `create_join_table(:users, :offers, table_name: "users_offers") do` instead of  `create_join_table :users, :offers do` if you see the method code here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table you will see that it automatically add two columns user_id and offer_id to the `users_offers` table and it will behave as foreign key because the table name is `user` and rails is intelligent enough to consider `user_id` as foreign_key, same for offers

Comment: @Athar. Thanks Athar for taking time to respond to my query. I appreciate it. Your suggestion has worked well. However, although I was able to create the users_offers table, I was not able to get the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in the model work. Even when I specify the join table in the model like...

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many: offers, join_table: users_offers

Comment: can you add the line you added for `has_and_belongs_to_many` association to your question or even as comment. it should be something like this `has_and_belongs_to_many :offers, join_table: "users_offers"`

Comment: @athar I realized that my changes that I made for the model association were not taking affect in rails console. Once I restarted the rails console then my changes took affect and everything worked. Thanks for checking in though and responding. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9):

You can define your join tables name with the `table_name` option.

```
create_join_table :users, :offers, table_name: :users_offers
```

There is also an option for setting column options called `column_options`, but I only got it to work for indexes and not for foreign keys.

```
create_join_table :users, :offers, column_options: { index: true }
```

This will create the desired indexes, but it ignores `foreign_key: true`. So you need to create them separately.

```
add_foreign_key :users_offers, :users
add_foreign_key :users_offers, :offers
```

In your models you need to add the relation like this:

```
# user.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :offers, join_table: :users_offers
```

And:

```
# offers.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :users_offers
```